# inherit from arbitrary number of template template classes

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Is it possible to pass an arbitrary number of template template classes to a class? Something like this:

```
template < template < typename > ... class types > struct T {};
```

When that's done, I'd like to inherit from them, like this:

```
template < typename p, template < typename > ... class types >
struct T : types <p> ... {};
```

How would I get that behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you've just misplaced the ellipsis, try this:

```
template < template < typename > class... types > struct T {};
```

Or to inherit from them:

```
template < typename p, template < typename > class... types >
struct T : types <p>... {};
```

Comment: Thank you! That went easier than expected.